# copy freebsd src using sysinstall

Tags: freebsd

i'm learning freebsd server, i need to install src from dvd (internet cost is high in my country so i'm using DVD to install packages) mount dvd with command mount -t cd9660 /dev/cd0 /media/cdrom it works. the problem is when i use sysinstall to install src it show me an error  dialog says error mounting /dev/cd0 on /dist:no such file or directory the /dist folder exists and google gives me nothing. any help is appreciated (freebsd version 9)

Comment: The version 9.x isn't supported (https://www.freebsd.org/security/security.html#sup). Could you try newest, supported version?

Comment: FreeBSD 9.x does not use sysinstall, it uses bsdinstall which is different

Answer (score 0):

Do not mount your DVD manually if you are installing packages via sysinstall. And, yes, FreeBSD-9.x Release is very outdated, try to find/download FreeBSD 11.1 Release: https://www.freebsd.org/where.html